# Add Foreign Key to existing table (error 1451)

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have two tables, with foreign keys, but when delete a record from 'fb_campaign' get follow error:

#1451 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mydb`.`fb_campaign_cat`, CONSTRAINT `fb_campaign_cat_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `fb_campaign` (`id_cat`))

Issue occurs when I add the second foreign key.

**table1: fb_campaign_cat**

```
+----+-----------+
| id |   fb_cat  |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | category1 |
|  2 | category2 |
|  3 | category3 |
+----+-----------+
```

**table2: fb_campaign**

```
+-------+--------+-----------+
| id_fb | id_cat |   name    |
+-------+--------+-----------+
|     1 |      1 | campaign1 |
|     2 |      2 | campaign2 |
+-------+--------+-----------+
```

** schema **

```
CREATE TABLE `fb_campaign_cat` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fb_cat` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `fb_campaign` (
  `id_fb` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_cat` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**FOREIGN KEY**

```
ALTER TABLE fb_campaign
ADD CONSTRAINT fb_campaign_cat 
FOREIGN KEY (id_cat) 
REFERENCES fb_campaign_cat(id) 
ON DELETE CASCADE;


ALTER TABLE fb_campaign_cat
ADD FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES fb_campaign(id_cat);
```

Comment: Provide complete `SHOW CREATE TABLe tablename;` output for both tables.

Comment: Added in my question. Thanks

Comment: No index for FK creation. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=377f588a3595bf8c7b343da2c3a7dd40

Comment: @Akina Working fine when delete records from 'fb_campaign', but when add a new category  in 'fb_campaign_cat'  withouth any related record in 'fb_campaign' get this error  #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mydb`.`fb_campaign_cat`, CONSTRAINT `fb_campaign_cat_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `fb_campaign` (`id_cat`))

Comment: ?? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d3b881a5d11e6b68cda2839432637b07

Comment: sorry, I correct my schema 'id' and 'id_fb' are both AUTO_INCREMENT.

Comment: Your new DDLs are inconsistent - MySQL will produce error (like "there must be only one autoincremented column and it must be primary key"). https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e1589c50774614eb2d35800afd147f7e

Answer (score 1):

The simple way would be to disable the foreign key check; make the changes then re-enable foreign key check.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; -- to disable them
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1; -- to re-enable them
```